# How to simulate a web browser to interact with a https server

Tags: c, http, ssl, browser

There is a website(using https protocol) that I can login with a username and a password in a web browser. Now I want to write a backend program to simulate this login action. How to do it? Give me some ideas.

update:
And there is a lot of javascript , is it possible to use curl to do this thing? Does curl can provide a js run time environment? If not, how to resolv the javascript things?

Comment: `Give me some ideas` -- Use `curl`.

Comment: Have you done any research or own efforts so far?

Comment: I used curl to process these things before, but in the situation of static website and http protocol. Now it is more complicated. It is a https website, and I need to execute javascript.

Comment: part1 (https) you just need to fill in (a lot) more curl_easy_setup()-Fields.

Comment: running javascript outa webbrowser requires a javascript-library.

Comment: curl won't help you. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a couple of months back, which is when I solved it by using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). If you are a Linux user and comfortable with CLI then it is very easy to use this tool. If you are a Windows or Mac user then also it must be simple to use.

This is a sample phantomjs code which I wrote sometime back. This will load a web page and  local.js JavaScript file. After which we can write normal JavaScript code to access and manipulate the DOM.

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
    page.open("http://localhost/localdir", function() {
        page.includeJs("http://localhost/local.js",
                function() {
                    var xml = page.evaluate(function() {
                        x = window.XML_VAR;
                        return x;
                    });
                    var json = page.evaluate(function() {
                        y = window.JSON_VAR;
                        return y;
                    });
                    var title = page.evaluate(function(){
                        z = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;
                        return z;
                    });
                    console.log(json);
                    console.log(xml);
                    console.log(title);
                    phantom.exit()
                });
});
```